# Difference equation particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

On an exam I was asked to find the solution $h$ for the following difference equation:

$h(n) - ah(n-1) = a\delta(n) - \delta(n-1)$

*Where $\delta(n)$ is the unit impulse.*

I was able to find the homogeneous solution as $h_h(n) = a^{n+1}$.
However, I did not know how to calculate the particular solution for this equation. My book does not cover this specific case, and I have a hard time finding coverage on the internet. Help would be very much appreciated.

For those wondering, I was not allowed to use the Z-transform.